# javax.net.ssl.SSLException while calling a webservice in Soap UI through HTTPS

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap, soapui

Hello fellow programmers!

I have to admit I'm still new to webservices and don't know exactly how to secure them.

I try to make a call to a webservice secured by ws-security in SoapUI. 
When I call WS without SSL, I get a proper answer. 
But when I call the WS through HTTPS, I receive status message:

```
Error getting response; javax.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

I thought that this is a problem with the SSL certificate, so I exported certificate from website and imported it to java keystore. Then I set this store in SoapUI configuration.
But without success.

I used Wireshark to capture connection session, with following result:

[image: Packet Transmission]

[image: TCP Stream]

In view of this situation, I have a few questions.

1. What could I have done wrong?
2. It's possible that site which provides this WS supports only non-SSL connections. Is there any way to check this?

Thanks in advance! Any help or suggestion will be appreciated :3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're connecting on the wrong (plain HTTP) port. It's not possible to run HTTPS and HTTP on the same port, so there will be another listening port for HTTPS in your config.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I actually resolved it thanks to your help.
However, I'm still surprised, because webservice now works, even if  keystore is not configured in SoapUI. (!) Is there any explanation to this behavior?